# How to calculate SNR of a image in python?

Tags: python

Want to know the correct method of calculating SNR of a single image.Added some gaussian noise to original image and want to calculate SNR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function as:

```
def signaltonoise(a, axis=0, ddof=0):
"""
The signal-to-noise ratio of the input data.
Returns the signal-to-noise ratio of `a`, here defined as the mean
divided by the standard deviation.
Parameters
----------
a : array_like
    An array_like object containing the sample data.
axis : int or None, optional
    Axis along which to operate. Default is 0. If None, compute over
    the whole array `a`.
ddof : int, optional
    Degrees of freedom correction for standard deviation. Default is 0.
Returns
-------
s2n : ndarray
    The mean to standard deviation ratio(s) along `axis`, or 0 where the
    standard deviation is 0.
"""
a = np.asanyarray(a)
m = a.mean(axis)
sd = a.std(axis=axis, ddof=ddof)
return np.where(sd == 0, 0, m/sd)
```

Source: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L1963